# Bind slave slow to update zones

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I have two Bind servers in a master/slave configuration. When the serial is incremented on the master zone file, it takes longer than expected for the zone to update on the slave. I have replicated the problem on two test servers. With a ttl of 5 secs, it takes serveral minutes for the slave to update. I am using Bind 9.8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Here's my configuration for the master test server:

named.conf.local

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.example.com.zone";
        //forwarders {};
        // If we do not comment the ''forwarders'' "empty" clients of the local subnet     in my case don't have access to the upstream DNS ?
        //allow-update { key ns-example-com_rndc-key; };
        allow-update { key rndc-key; };
        //confusion between the file name to import (ns-example-com_rndc-key) and the     key label (rndc-key) ?
};
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/db.example.com.inv.zone";
    //see comment below (zone "example.com")
    //forwarders {};
    //allow-update { key ns-example-com_rndc-key; };
    allow-update { key rndc-key; };
};
```

db.root.example.com

```
$TTL    5
@       IN      SOA   sid.example.com. root.example.com. (
               2007010416           ; Serial
                       5           ; Refresh [1m]
                      5           ; Retry   [10m]
                    5           ; Expire  [1d]
                      5 )         ; Negative Cache TTL [1h]
;
@       IN      NS      sid.example.com.
@       IN      MX      10 sid.example.com.

sid     IN      A       192.168.0.3
etch    IN      A       192.168.0.3

pop     IN      CNAME   sid
www     IN      CNAME   sid
mail    IN      CNAME   sid
```

db.example.com.inv.zone

```
@ IN SOA        sid.example.com. root.example.com. (
               2007010401           ; Serial
                     3600           ; Refresh [1h]
                      600           ; Retry   [10m]
                    86400           ; Expire  [1d]
                      600 )         ; Negative Cache TTL [1h]
;
@       IN      NS      sid.example.com.

1       IN      PTR     sid.example.com.
2       IN      PTR     etch.example.com.
```

Here's the configuration for the slave:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/cache/bind/db.example.com.zone";
    masters { 192.168.0.2; };
//forwarders {};
    // If we do not comment the ''forwarders'' "empty" clients of the local subnet in my case don't have access to the upstream DNS ?
    //allow-update { key ns-example-com_rndc-key; };
    allow-update { key rndc-key; };
    //confusion between the file name to import (ns-example-com_rndc-key) and the key label (rndc-key) ?
};
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/cache/bind/db.example.com.inv.zone";
    masters { 192.168.0.2; };
//see comment below (zone "example.com")
    //forwarders {};
    //allow-update { key ns-example-com_rndc-key; };
    allow-update { key rndc-key; };
};
```

Comment: Looks OK to me, but I've never heard of anyone using such short refresh values. Typically you'd use `notify` to get zone changes (almost) instantly to your slave servers. Why not use that?

Comment: The sort refresh values are just on the test servers. What is `notify`? Is it in the reference manual?

Comment: I also find that adding also-notify { a.b.c.d; }; to your named.conf can sometimes help

Answer (score 5):

From the copy-left guide [DNS for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html):

> By default BIND9 will send NOTIFY messages to all the target names (right-hand names) that appear in NS RRs for the zone

So you need to add your slave server as a NS entry in `db.example.com.inv.zone`.

Additionally, you may need to add the settings:

- In the master: `notify yes;` and `allow-transfer { SLAVE_IP; };`
- In the slave: `allow-notify { MASTER_IP; };`

Answer (score 4):

When the serial number is changed on the master, it will notify the slave immediately. In other words, `notify` is enabled by default. BUT, the way notify works is, the master looks at the `NS records` of that particular domain in the zone file, and notifies the servers listed in the NS record, excluding itself. In your case, I don't see the slave server's hostname being listed as an NS record in the db.root.example.com zone file. Therefore, the slave is contacting the master, listed in the slave's config file - `masters { 192.168.0.2; };` at the Refresh interval, 1 hour. That is why it is taking long time to update.

Solution - add the NS record for the slave, also include its IP address as an A record. Typical setup is as follows -

```
  @        IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
  @        IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
  ns1     IN      A       192.168.1.1
  ns2     IN      A       192.168.1.2
```

First and third line, for master. Second and fourth line for slave.